# Subset parameter

Tags: coq

I have a set as a parameter:

```
Parameter Q:Set.
```

Now I want to define another parameter that is a subset of Q. Something like:

```
Parameter F: subset Q.
```

How I can define that? I guess I can add the restriction later as an axiom, but seems more natural to express it directly in the type of F.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't express it directly.

It's misleading to think of objects in `Set` as mathematical sets. `Set` is the sort of datatypes, the same kinds of types that you find in programming languages (except that Coq's types are very powerful).

Coq doesn't have subtyping¹. If the two types `F` and `Q` are distinct, then they are disjoint, as far as the mathematical model is concerned.

The usual approach is to declare `F` as a completely related set, and declare a canonical injection from `F` to `Q`. You'll want to specify any interesting property of that injection, beyond the obvious.

```
Parameter Q : Set.
Parameter F : Set.
Parameter inj_F_Q : F -> Q.
Axiom inj_F_Q_inj : forall x y : F, inj_F_Q x = inj_F_Q y -> x = y.
Coercion inj_F_Q : F >-> Q.
```

That last line declares a coercion from `F` to `Q`. That lets you put an object of type `F` wherever the context requires the type `Q`. The type inference engine will insert a call to `inj_F_Q`. You will need to write the coercion explicitly occasionally, since the type inference engine, while very good, is not perfect (perfection would be mathematically impossible). There is a chapter on coercions in the Coq reference manual; you should at least skim through it.

Another approach is to define your subset with an extensional property, i.e. declare a predicate `P` on the set (the type) `Q` and define `F` from `P`.

```
Parameter Q : Set.
Parameter P : Q -> Prop.
Definition G := sig P.
Definition inj_G_Q : G -> Q := @proj1_sig Q P.
Coercion inj_G_Q : G >-> Q.
```

`sig` is a specification, i.e. a weak sum type, i.e. a pair consisting of an object and a proof that said object has a certain property. `sig P` is eta-equivalent to `{x | P x}` (which is syntactic sugar `sig (fun x => P x)`). You have to decide whether you prefer the short or the long form (you need to be consistent). The `Program` vernacular is often useful when working with weak sums.

¹ 
<sub>There is subtyping in the module language, but that's not relevant here. And coercions fake subtyping well enough for many uses, but they're not the real thing.</sub>

Comment: A very instructive answer! But is there a way in Coq to encapsulate all this extra code? I need to do this pretty often, and I'd rather not have to add three lines of code to every instance.

Comment: @mhelvens I don't think so, but I'm a bit out of practice these days. I think you can easily extend the vernacular if you're willing to write a bit of Ocaml code.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks! --- I've asked a somewhat more general question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874341/consistent-formulations-of-sets-in-coq. If you have something to add I'd really appreciate it. (It's so hard to find people with Coq experience.)